# Finding the data sources info on Websphere

Tags: websphere-8

We have multiple data sources in QA and some of them are pointing to PROD. I have modified the serverames to QA and did test connection, it was successful. Still some of the queries are getting extracted from the PROD. How do I validate that if changes made are correct? and is it only resources.xml?

Changes in the Data sources - server info
Test connection
validated in resources.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, resources.xml will show your current configuration.

TestConnection will always use your current configuration.

However, Websphere 8.5.5 does not have a dynamic configuration.

After updating your configuration to use the QA instead of the PROD database, your application will still use PROD until you restart your server.

Comment: When you say 8.5.5 does not have dynamic configuration, Can we not change the server name of PROD to QA. ?

Comment: You can update your configuration, but that update will not take effect until you restart your server.